# How to pass styles from computed to template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I create in computed method which change color depending on the status. I think its correct, but I still dont see my result :/

template:

```
.status_values
   span.color(:style="changeColorStatus")
```

vue.js

```
 computed: {
  changeColorStatus() {
    let status = this.loan.schedule;
    status.map(e => {
      console.log(e.delay);
      if (e.delay == 0) {
        return "background-color:green";
      }
      if (e.delay <= 5) {
      return "background-color: lightgreen";
      }
      if (e.delay > 5) {
        return "background-color: red ";
      }
      if (e.status == "" && e.delay == 0 && e.debt > 0) {
      return "background-color: lightgray ";
      }
    });
  }
  },
```

It is possible, that I should do this in method, not in the computed? In  console.log(e.delay) i see all deley numbers, so in if I can compare them. It looks quite easy but doesnt work.

Comment: Do you know that adding inline styling is considered as a bad practice? Use classes instead. It'd be much easier and much much better.

Comment: ok. thank you for suggestion, but pleas tell me why it is doesnt work? What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass a Javascript object to the `style` attribute.

For example, instead of returning `"background-color:green"`, you should return `{'background-color': 'green'}`.

Inside a `*.vue` file, it looks like  this :

```
<template>
  <div id="app" :style="styleApp">
    Hello
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "App",
  computed: {
    styleApp: function () {
      return {
        'background-color': 'green'
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thak you for you answer. Is this the same for a class?  If i have similar situation but with class: span.color(:class="changeColorStatus"), this description doesnt work:        if (e.delay == 0) {
          return {"class" : "green"}
        }

Comment: You can use `return {green: true}`. There are multiple ways of setting a `:class`, it's very clearly documentated [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax).